# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') RTK Query

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to port my project from RTK to RTK Query. It was working perfectly with Redux toolkit but my manager wants me to use RTK query instead. I can't quite get why it's giving this error here. What am I doing wrong? If I console log data and I can see the data it says 'undefined'

```js
import { useCustomersQuery } from "../../../../features/rtkquery/customersApi";

  const {data, error, isLoading, isSuccess, isFetching} = useCustomersQuery();

  console.log(data)

< Tbody > {
    data
    .map((customers) => {
      return ( <
        CustomersTable key = {
          customers.uid
        }
        name = {
          `${customers.first_name} ${customers.last_name}`
        }
        logo = {
          customers.logo
        }
        id = {
          customers.uid
        }
        exchange = {
          customers.exchange
        }
        createdAt = {
          moment(customers.createdAt).format('LLL')
        }
  /Tbody>
```

```js
import {
  createApi,
  fetchBaseQuery
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const customersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "customersApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {
      getState
    }) => {
      const token = getState().auth.user.token;
      if (token) {
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      }

      return headers
    },
  }),

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    customers: builder.query({
      query: () => '/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer',
    })
  })
})

export const {
  useCustomersQuery
} = customersApi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably still loading at this point, and you have to render something before it's finished with that.

Do something like

```
if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
if (isError) return <div>oh no, an error!</div>
```

before you return the real jsx of the component.